# ESX Server Setup cannot detect my LAN card

Tags: installation, local-area-network, drivers, vmware-esx, adapter

I want to install esx server on my system that has LAN card, (Realtec RTL-8110sc)

How to install it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that the Realtec card is not on VMware's [Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.vmware.com/go/hcl).

Comment: You can use the above link to check if the card is supported or not. If it is not, then you're out of luck with regards to that specific card. At that point, you would need to consider adding a PCI/PCIe card that is supported by VMware.

Comment: Wow, Is there any way to install with unsupported cards?

Comment: No. The ESX hypervisor is monolithic. You can't add in extra drivers or customise it. Fortunately, NICs with compatible chipsets are widely available and consumer-priced options are available.